# signed multiplication with too many carries

Tags: binary

I'm trying to multiply two signed binary numbers : 111011 and 110100.

I'm using the methodology found [here](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/technical-articles/multiplication-examples-using-the-fixed-point-representation/).

I'm not completely sure I'm wrong, maybe I'm just misinterpreting the results but anyway :

When I perform the additions of the partial products, on the leftmost column I have, including the carried bits, 1+1+1+1 (all the partial products were sign extended to match the length of the final result which should be 6+6=12) which means that I get a carry 2 bits to the left making my resulting number 14 bits long. I think the result of a multiplication shouldn't exceed the sum of the lengths of the multiplicands, but then I surely couldn't sign extend the partial product or this would always happen. What exactly is wrong here? And if it's correct how should I know how many bits to discard? I can only imagine if the word was 128 bit long, then I'd have to discard countless bits? So that can't be right.

The sign extended partial products I'm getting are:

### 111011 * 110100 =

**000000**000000 +

**00000**000000 +

**1111**111011 +

**000**000000 +

**11**111011 +

0000101 =

10 000000111100

(the last partial product is the 2s complement of the first multiplicand, as per the instructions in the link)

So I ask again: what exactly is wrong? Thanks in advance!